# MySql case when to sum up the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to run case when to give me the quatity per location. I just can not have the format of the results I want.

I have simple table:

```
create table rot (
            code int(10) primary key,
            PN varchar(10) not null,
            Qty int(10) not null,
                Loc varchar(10));

insert into rot values (1,'T1',5,'a');
insert into rot values (2,'A1',6,'b');
insert into rot values (3,'J1',1,'c');
insert into rot values (4,'A2',2,'a');
insert into rot values (5,'J2',1,'b');
insert into rot values (6,'A3',2,'c');
insert into rot values (7,'J3',3,'d');
insert into rot values (8,'T1',3,'e');
insert into rot values (9,'A1',3,'a');
insert into rot values (10,'J2',3,'c');
insert into rot values (11,'J2',3,'d');
insert into rot values (12,'A1',1,'c');
insert into rot values (13,'J2',0,'e');
```

And I want to transform it into the below format:

```
PN  a   b   c   d   e
A1  3   6   1       
A2  2               
A3          2       
J1          1       
J2      1       3   0
J3              3   
T1  5               3
```

I use the following CASE WHEN but does not result in the above mention format:

```
SELECT 
   PN
 ,(CASE WHEN Loc = 'a'  THEN Qty END) AS 'a'
 ,(CASE WHEN Loc = 'b'  THEN Qty END) AS 'b'
 ,(CASE WHEN Loc = 'c'  THEN Qty END) AS 'c'
 ,(CASE WHEN Loc = 'd'  THEN Qty END) AS 'd'
 ,(CASE WHEN Loc = 'e'  THEN Qty END) AS 'e'


FROM rot

GROUP BY PN
```

When I use  `,SUM(CASE WHEN Loc = 'a'  THEN Qty END) AS 'a'` instead it gives the same results.

Comment: It works with `sum`  also see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47ebae/5)

Comment: With sum it works... I've just tried your example, and it gives all the results you want... the way you want it

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregate function `max` in order to pick values according to your group by crteria

```
SELECT 
   PN
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN Loc = 'a'  THEN Qty END) AS 'a'
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN Loc = 'b'  THEN Qty END) AS 'b'
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN Loc = 'c'  THEN Qty END) AS 'c'
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN Loc = 'd'  THEN Qty END) AS 'd'
 ,MAX(CASE WHEN Loc = 'e'  THEN Qty END) AS 'e'
FROM rot
GROUP BY PN
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47ebae/3)